# Writing text side-by-side

Tags: formatting, two-column, text-manipulation, grid-typesetting

Can someone please help me figure out how to write two columns of text side by side for just a short region of a page in `LaTeX`? As a MWE please see the attached pic.

Edit : I just want to write two parallel text in just a short region of space. Sort of like a table used for comparison.

[image: MWE Image]

Comment: You can use the `multicols` package.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry, I don't think I am looking for that. I just want to write two parallel text in just a short region of space. Sort of like a table used for comparison.

Comment: You can use a tabular, too.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Let me try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tabular environment for that. If you use the `m{width}` spec (which requires the package array), it will wrap the text and center it vertically. To make sure the arrows are also centered horizontally, you need to add `>{\centering}`.

Thus the MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{0.4\textwidth} >{\centering}m{2em} m{0.4\textwidth}}
\lipsum[1][2-3] &  $\longleftrightarrow$ & \lipsum[1][5-6] \\
&&\\
\centering Temp $T$ &  $\longleftrightarrow$ & \centering period  $\uparrow_B$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with minipage?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth}
\leftarrow
\\
\\
\rightarrow
\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea\\ 
\end{minipage}

\newline
\newline
\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Edit: remove unnecesary data from template, changed values to centered version
Edit2: Added Arrows

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't look like what I want to achieve. The final look is also weird and I can't place any arrows there like in the pic I attached.

Comment: Ah sorry didnt think of the arrows as relevant my bad. please see above i added them via new minipage, might not be the most elegant solution and positioning will be a pain

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does indeed work but I can accept only one answer and the other one seems better to me. Apologies.